# GoTo to a label in another function

Tags: objective-c, ios

i need to do like this:

```
-(void)function1{
goto start;
}

-(void)function2{
//some code
start://i need to get in here exactly, [self function2] oblige me to execute the function2 from the beginning
//some code..
}
```

Seems i can not, what can i do instead? thanx in advance.

**EDIT**: here is my actual code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                              @"Select quiz,question,p1,p2,p3,num_correct from question where quiz=(select id from quiz where nom = \'%@\' and niveau= \'%i\' and theme=(select id from theme where nom=\'%@\'))",nomPartieQuiz,quiIslam.theGameLevel,quiIslam.themeChoisie];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, 
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
        start://étiquette
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW && !passToNextQuestion)
            {



                NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] 
                                          initWithUTF8String:
                                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                             statement, 1)];

                NSLog(@"%@",addressField); 
                txtView.text=addressField;

                passToNextQuestion=NO;                                

            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }

}


-(IBAction)clickOnTheButton:(id)sender{

    btn1.hidden=YES;
    goto start;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code so we can see the reasoning behind using  the goto?

Comment: Edited, please take a look :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)function1{
 [self function2];
}

-(void)function2{

//some code..
}
```

And, using "gotos" its only allowed in a very very very specifically kind of situations,  you should forget about them right now! It goes again any developing principle.

Comment: I don't need to just go to `function2`, i need to go to a specific line in `function2`

Comment: If you NEED to 'goto' any specific line in your code, you've messed up somewhere pretty badly. As this answer says, you should move whatever code you need executed in the goto to a method and just call that rather than jumping out of your current method. If you don't want to execute any more logic after the method, just call return; and exit the method.

Comment: Totally agree, just review your code, there's to be a different way of doing things than a GOTO, really, Ive been developing for years and I've never used it, for sure you dont need to!

Comment: I think so too, thanx for clarifications :)

Comment: I always use `goto` for resource cleanup in C functions. What's the counterpart in Objective C?

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your edit, put the logic for the start: into it's own method, then call that method from your viewWillAppear and from any other place you need to execute it. Keep in mind you may need to make some variable global so your method can see them, but this is the idea, even if you have to modify the execution.

```
-(void)sqlStartLogic {
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW && !passToNextQuestion)
   {
                NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] 
                                          initWithUTF8String:
                                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
       NSLog(@"%@",addressField); 
       txtView.text=addressField;

       passToNextQuestion=NO;                                
   }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}

-(void)function2 {
   [self sqlStartLogic];
}
```